# Get Query ID of a snowflake query using Go interface

Tags: go, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the Query ID of the query that I am executing on snowflake by interfacing through Golang. On the snowflake UI after executing the query, we get a link to the query ID along with the results. I'm not sure how to get this query ID programmatically. Not sure if I'm doing it right but this is what I have - connection to snowflake using connection string; use this connection to execute the query. Along with the result, I want the query ID as well. I'm new to snowflake, any help on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
)

var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    db, err := sql.Open("snowflake", "<connection string>")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func callDB() {
    type result struct {
        ID   string
        Name string
    }

    row := db.QueryRow("SELECT ID, NAME FROM EMPLOYEE") // get query id as well
    if err := row.Scan(&result.ID, &result.Name); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

func main() {
    callDB()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query ID using the `SnowflakeResult` or `SnowflakeError`, or you can also submit a query directly to Snowflake to use the `LAST_QUERY_ID` function available in SQL.  Here are some reference documents for you:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_query_id.html

https://godoc.org/github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake

Comment: Can you maybe give an example of how I could use `type SnowflakeResult interface{}` in my code?

Comment: It's still a mystery how to use `type SnowflakeResult interface{}`. Finally I was able to use reflection to get QueryID, maybe this helps: https://gist.github.com/ralfbecher/210408184329d83b37cac309cb4ef2ef